# Mutate column of dataframe using values stored in different dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have created two dataframes, with `df.1` containing my main data.

```
ID  A_ratio   B_ratio  C_ratio
1    0.9       7.6      3.5
2    3.1       4.4      0.7     
3    6.3       8.2      1.2
```

The dataframe `cut` only contains one row.

```
A_cut  B_cut  C_cut
 4.5    5.3    2.0
```

I now want to use the values stored in `cut` to binarize `df`, turning `X_ratio <= X_cut` to `1` and `X_ratio > X_cut` to `0`. The new column could be called `X_bin`.  I've tried the following `dplyr` approach:

```
df.2 <- df.1 %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with("ratio"), ~if_else(. <= get(cut[str_replace(cur_column(),"ratio","cut")]), 1, 0)
            .names = "{.col}_bin"))%>%
  rename_with(~str_replace(.,"_ratio",""),contains("_ratio_"))
  select(ID, ends_with("bin"))
```

But I'm unfortunately  getting an `Error: unexpected symbol`. Could someone point out my mistake? The desired output in `df.2` would be

```
ID A_bin B_bin C_bin
1   1     0     0
2   1     1     1
3   0     0     1
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `,` missing before the `.names` and if we are extracting the column from `cut`, we don't need any `get` along with the fact that instead of `mutate`, use `transmute` to return only those columns needed so that the last step with `select` can be removed

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df.1 %>%
  transmute(ID, across(ends_with("ratio"), 
      ~if_else(. <=  cut[[str_replace(cur_column(),"ratio","cut")]], 
            1, 0),
        .names = "{.col}_bin")) %>% 
   rename_with(~str_replace(.,"_ratio",""),contains("_ratio_"))
```

-output

```
#  ID A_bin B_bin C_bin
#1  1     1     0     0
#2  2     1     1     1
#3  3     0     0     1
```

---

As we are returning binary columns, `if_else` is not really needed.  The logical vector can be coerced to binary with `as.integer` or wrapped with `+(`

```
df.1 %>%
  transmute(ID, across(ends_with("ratio"), 
      ~as.integer(. <=  cut[[str_replace(cur_column(),"ratio","cut")]]),
        .names = "{.col}_bin")) %>% 
   rename_with(~str_replace(.,"_ratio",""),contains("_ratio_"))
```

Note: `cut` is a function name, so it is better not to name objects with function names

#### data

```
df.1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, A_ratio = c(0.9, 3.1, 6.3), B_ratio = c(7.6, 
4.4, 8.2), C_ratio = c(3.5, 0.7, 1.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

cut <- structure(list(A_cut = 4.5, B_cut = 5.3, C_cut = 2), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Comment: Ah, thank you so much for this answer, works out perfectly. Also thanks for the very helpful remarks, will definitely try to follow them from now on!

Answer (score 3):

Base R answer :

```
df.1[-1] <- +(sweep(df.1[-1], 2, unlist(cut), `<=`))
df.1

#  ID A_ratio B_ratio C_ratio
#1  1       1       0       0
#2  2       1       1       1
#3  3       0       0       1
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Didn't know there was such an easy and elegant way using base R!

Answer (score 2):

**purrr**

```r
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, A_ratio = c(0.9, 3.1, 6.3), B_ratio = c(7.6, 
                                                                         4.4, 8.2), C_ratio = c(3.5, 0.7, 1.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                     -3L))

cut <- structure(list(A_cut = 4.5, B_cut = 5.3, C_cut = 2), class = "data.frame",
                 row.names = c(NA, 
                               -1L))
library(purrr)
df[-1] <- +map2_dfc(df[-1], cut, ~.x <= .y)
df
#>   ID A_ratio B_ratio C_ratio
#> 1  1       1       0       0
#> 2  2       1       1       1
#> 3  3       0       0       1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>